# using api to delete spreadsheet and some problem with it

Tags: api, spreadsheet

there are more than 30 spreadsheets in my account, but there are only 2 on the disk, how is this possible ? the spreadsheets were created by the api, and I tried to delete them myself, but after refreshe the page , they still exist . what's happening? how can I delete it myself and how can I delete it using the api forever and how can I delete them if they are not on the disk ? please help , i have no idea

Answer (score 0):

I found out that very often Google has lags , with the use Google drive  api, you can delete all of them and then after a while they disappear when viewed through the browser

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).